# creating exception classes that inherit from io classes in C++

Tags: c++, templates, exception, inheritance, stringstream

Please forgive my C++ naiveté

I was thinking of creating Exception classes that would inherit from std::stringstream so that I could use stringstream’s operator << to build up text error messages while at the same time being able to try catch the exceptions by type.

My code is something like

```
class ExceptionXYZ : public std::stringstream
{};

Void someFunction()
{
   try
   {
      //do something
   }
   catch(const ExceptionXYZ& e)
   {
      //handle XYZ
   }
```

Unfortunately my VS2008 compiler doesn’t like this and complains that

> error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot
>   access private member declared in class
>   'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'

basic_ios is a great grandparent (or thereabouts) of stringstream and there must be some implicit access violation somewhere, but between my extremely rusty C++ and the compiler’s unhelpful error message (it doesn’t tell me what private member it’s worried about) I’m a bit lost.

I imagine people do this kind of thing all the time (i.e. throw exceptions with text that have to be caught by type).

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I can't understand why you would want to do this. Can you explain your use case?

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a `std::stringstream` as a base class for exception because you cannot copy or move a `stringstream` (because of the `streambuffer` inside if you have a look at the error message) and that is a requirement for an object to be thrown. So it cannot compile when I do this kind of code:

```
class ExceptionXYZ : public std::stringstream {};

void test_except() throw (ExceptionXYZ)
{
  ExceptionXYZ xyz;

  xyz << "This exception is useless";
  throw xyz;
}
```

http://ideone.com/NQUunh

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't inherit from stream classes just to use them during construction. If you really need to build up the error message you might choose to rather store the information needed to build it upon request or build it up on construction.

From the sounds of it you want to do something like this:

```
throw ExceptionXYZ() << "some " << information << " or " << other;
```

That's not going to work too well anyway because the `operator<<()` would all return `std::ostream&` rather than the exception object you'd want.

Answer (score 0):

(Most) types in the STD are designed to not be used as base classes. Only use them as member variables.

To give a message to your exception you could do something like this:

```
class ExceptionXYZ
{
public:
   ExceptionXYZ(const std::string& msg) : msg_(msg) {}
   const std::string& get_message() const { return msg_; }
private:
   std::string msg_;
};

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Error " << 42;
throw ExceptionXYZ(ss.str());
```

Comment: Actually, there are a couple of classes in the standard C++ library which are intended to be derived from (e.g., `std::streambuf` and the various facets). The class `std::istream` and `std::ostream` are also intended to be used as base classes, although only for streams initializing their respective base and holding the necessary objects (e.g., the `std::filebuf` or the `std::stringbuf`).

Comment: Never say never ;) I changed it to "most". For example there is probably something fishy with your design if you use `vector`, `list`, `map` or `set` as a base class...

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Do you have a reference which indicates that `istream` and `ostream` are intended to be used as base classes? I have never seen this.

Comment: `std::ifstream` and `std::istringstream` are derived from `std::istream`. Likewise for `std::ofstream` and `std::ostringstream`. If I recall correctly Nicolai Josuttis's "The C++ Standard Library" describes how to derive from the stream classes (of course, you may discount this as a reference as I wrote major parts of the IOStreams chapter).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Now I would argue that i/ofstream and i/ostringstream are part of the std itself, thus are not a use case where the "user" derives from them. In some C++ book I picked up the idiom "never derive from STD classes - always use them as members", but perhaps this is outdated...

Comment: the books isn't wrong. It just doesn't cover the IOStreams and locales area :-) My point is that you'd derive from `std::istream` pretty much the same way `std::ifstream` if you create a custom, user-defined stream. Of course, the key functionality is implemented in a class derived from `std::streambuf` and the whole point of the class derived from `std::istream` is to set the `std::istream` up with the custom stream buffer in a convenient way.

Comment: Thanks Danvil. This is what I have already. I was hoping to make an "is a" rather than "has a" redux.  However if stringstream cannot be copied I take Johan's point above that it cannot be thrown, rather unfortunate....